# Create a directory during .deb installation with read write access rights using cmaklist.txt

Tags: 14.04, permissions, deb, cmake

I need to create a directory at the path `/opt/` with read write permission for everyone (777 permission) during .deb installation on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit .

I have no root login on my machine so I can get the root access by `sudo` and I am installing the .deb with `sudo` on my machine.

Right now I am using:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/mydirectory/
```

But I want that this directory create with read write permission for everyone.

I am using the command:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS app RUNTIME DESTINATION /opt/mydirectory)
```

in my cmakelist.txt file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create this directory in your `debian/rules` makefile or `debian/postinst` script if you're creating a debian package. Otherwise could you please detail where comes this cmakelist.txt?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're building your own deb package, right?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for reply. Can you please describe me more, how can I create directory in debian/rules file or use debian/postinst script for the same. Any example please. Btw I am using cmakelist.txt file to for SET CMAKE PATH,FIND PACKAGE,INCLUDE THIRD PARTY LIBRARIES, ADD EXEXUTABLES, LINK THIRD PARTY LIBRARIES, INSTALL FILES PATH, ADD QT5 MODULES etc.

Comment: I proposed a `debian/my_package.postint`, that way you don't need to change your existing `debian/rules` or the `cmakelist.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following `debian/my_package.postint` to create the directory and change its permissions:

```
#!/bin/sh

#DEBHELPER#

set -e

mkdir -p /opt/mydirectory
chmod 777 /opt/mydirectory
```

Then build your package with `dpkg-buildpackage -b` for example.

Comment: Ok, Will try this and let you know.

Comment: I have tried the same as you suggested but still unable to change the 777 permission to the /opt/mydirectory. FYI, I have no root login on my machine so I can get the root access by sudo and I am installing the .deb with sudo on my machine. I hvae added the mkdir -p /opt/mydirectory
chmod 777 /opt/mydirectory in the debian/postinst.ex file to create the directory and INSTALL(TARGETS app RUNTIME DESTINATION /opt/mydirectory) in my cmakelist.txt file to install the app exexutable at the path /opt/mydirectory. I was taking lunch so sorry for the delay in response.

Comment: @manojpatidar The file to create is `debian/postinst` not `debian/postinst.ex`. Please try without the `.ex` extension

Comment: Thank you @Sylvain Pineau. It solved my problem. I have used postinst without .ex and it is fixed.

Comment: Well, `.ex` means example. Those files are automatically created by `dh_make -s`. You can safely remove them

Comment: After the above process I am running my app with sudo (root permission) and during in running app, the app created some directories with root permission. So I want to change permission to 777 on these directories by running the app from sudo. Can anyone help me  in this ? Can I do the same by the debian files ? Thanks.

Comment: @manojpatidar Create a new question please

Comment: @manojpatidar, if you're calling `mkdir` from your app, maybe just `mkdir -m 777  foo` is enough

Comment: Yes but I need to do the same from the debian files beacuse I am creating my own .deb file. So can I ? Thanks

Comment: @manojpatidar humm, it's not clear if you create those dir from your installed app of from a script/makefile in your debian at build time. A new question describing your exact problem will be better I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17170/discussion-between-manojpatidar-and-sylvain-pineau).